# If $x_n \rightarrow 0$ and $\{y_n\}$ is a bounded sequence, then $x_ny_n \rightarrow 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $x_n \to 0 $ and let $(y_n)$ be a sequence such that $(y_n)$ is bounded. Show that $(x_ny_n) \to 0 $

**My try**

Since $(y_n)$ is bounded, we can find some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|y_n| < \alpha $ for all $n$. Next, let $\epsilon > 0 $ be given and find some $N > 0$ such that $|x_n| < \frac{ \epsilon}{ \alpha } $ for all $n > N $. Notice,

$$|x_ny_n| = |x_n||y_n| < \frac{ \epsilon}{\alpha} \cdot \alpha = \epsilon$$

To show that $(x_ny_n) \to 0 $, is it enough to take the same $N$ as before? so that $|x_ny_n| < \epsilon $ for all $n > N $

Comment: Yes, this looks just fine.

Comment: Just be careful of your $\alpha$. It must be a point so that $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+$. And yes, the same $N$ works because $y_n$ is bounded independent of whether $x_n$ converges or not.

Answer (score 1):

Given $(y_n)$ is bounded, i.e., $\exists M\in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $|y_n|<M,\forall n$.
$\therefore 0\le|x_ny_n|<M|x_n|,\forall n$.

Now $\lim0\le\lim|x_ny_n|\le\lim M|x_n|$.
$\therefore\lim|x_ny_n|=0\implies \lim x_ny_n=0$.

$\therefore(x_ny_n)\to 0$